# Word alignment task vs dictionary induction

Tags: nlp, word-embedding

I've been reading up on multi-lingual word embedding methods, and couldn't quite grasp the difference between two of the evaluation methods used - word alignment and dictionary induction.
My curiosity was heightened by looking at Table 1 from [this paper](https://levyomer.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/a-strong-baseline-for-learning-cross-lingual-word-embeddings-eacl-20171.pdf), where the Bilingual Autoencoders methods overperforms Inverted index for the Word Alignment task, but it's the other way around for Dictionary Induction.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a one-to-one individual word mapping. Inducing such mapping implies that given one word, the corresponding most commonly used word (lexical form) in another language is retrieved.

In word alignment, this involves whole sentences or text chunks. Therefore this adds context and specifies the semantic meaning (removing disambiguation). E.g. whereas the word "rock" by itself has the common meaning of a geological object in a dictionary, in the sentence "I love rock music", this would have to be aligned with a word that does not have the same meaning (i.e. solves the disambiguation).